there is an app in which i am facing orob related to models
"I've developed a yoga app, but I'm encountering issues with the model. Ideally, when users select a specific yoga asana, the app should accurately detect their body posture and provide feedback on whether it's correct or incorrect. However, it seems that this feature isn't working as intended.
i want a specified ans

If you want a specific answer, then you must provide a specific question. There isn't enough information here for anyone to be able to help. You need to be very specific about what you're doing, including what's the issue with the model you mentioned before and showing the reproducible code that you're trying to run. Giving us a vague, non-specific description of an issue isn't meaningful. Include the EXACT steps for everything you're doing.
